# How can I get my custom modal to work in with my js

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-popup

This is a fiddle I have with it working but I would not like to apply it within magento

http://jsfiddle.net/7yhmkf98/

I have a requirejs-comfig.js file set uo like this

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        wow: 'js/wow',
        modernizr: 'js/modernizr.custom.49511',
        hotspot: 'js/jquery.hotspot.min',
        venobox: 'js/venobox',
        popup: 'js/popup'
        },
    shim: {
        wow: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        modernizr: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        hotspot: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        venobox: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        popup: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/collapsible': {
                'js/mage/collapsible-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I also tried to link it in my default_head_blocks.xml but nothing works.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find the solution to your problem?  I am also looking to integrate Venobox to work on Magento 2